# My Rust script that calculates primes seems to freeze at 16777213

Tags: rust, primes

I'm new to the Rust language, and I've been working on this, my first Rust project, to get a better grasp of how the lang works. I've got this code that calculates primes, but it stops every time it reaches the value 16,777,213. It doesn't panic, it doesn't crash, it just freezes.
I've found another post where someone tried a similar thing in C++ and has the same problem: [Prime number generator stops abruptly at 16777213 | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383161/prime-number-generator-stops-abruptly-at-16777213), but nobody seems to answer how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```rust
fn half(val: i128) -> bool { // For better precision (to prevent false positives in small numbers)
    let mut factors: Vec<i128> = vec![];
    for i in 1i128..(((val as f32)/2.0)+1.0) as i128 {
        let factor: f32 = (val as f32)/(i as f32);
        if factor == factor.round() {
                let factor:i128 = factor as i128;
                if factor != val {
                    factors.push(factor as i128)
                }
            }
        }
    if factors.is_empty() {
        return true
    } else {false}
}
fn root(val:i128) -> bool {
    let mut factors: Vec<i128> = vec![];
    for i in 1i128..((val as f32).sqrt().round()+1.0) as i128 {
        if val > 2 {
            let factor: f32 = (val as f32)/(i as f32);
            if factor == factor.round() {
                let factor: i128 = factor as i128;
                if factor != val {
                    factors.push(factor)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if factors.is_empty() {
        return true
    } else {false}
}
fn is_prime(val:i128) -> bool {
    if val > 100 {
        root(val)
    }
    else {
        half(val)
    }
}
fn main() {
    //let mut primes: Vec<i128> = vec![];
    let mut i:i128 = 16_700_000;
    loop {
        let prime: bool = is_prime(i);
        if prime {
            println!("{}",i)
            /*
This was the original code, but I removed the vector so that I'd be able to
determine the exact value at which the script breaks at.
            primes.push(i);
            if primes.len() as i32 == 24 {
                println!("{:?}",primes);
                primes.clear()
            }*/
        }
        i += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the linked Q&A and I saw advice that, when applied, should fix that problem (but who knows, that may reveal the next problem). So, not quite "nobody seems to answer how to fix it".

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace all `f32` by `f64`. I will try to explain it more deeply, but now found that this fixing problem.

Firstly to simplify we can assume that `if val > 100` is always true and exclude `half` function from considerations.

Now we can rewrite our program to see differences between f32 and f64 versions:

```rust
fn root_64(val:i128) -> bool {
    let mut factors: Vec<i128> = vec![];
    for i in 1i128..((val as f64).sqrt().round()+1.0) as i128 {
        if val > 2 {
            let factor: f64 = (val as f64)/(i as f64);
            if factor == factor.round() {
                let factor: i128 = factor as i128;
                if factor != val {
                    factors.push(factor)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println!("F64 {} {:?}", val, factors);
    if factors.is_empty() {
        return true
    } else {false}
}

fn root_32(val:i128) -> bool {
    let mut factors: Vec<i128> = vec![];
    for i in 1i128..((val as f32).sqrt().round()+1.0) as i128 {
        if val > 2 {
            let factor: f32 = (val as f32)/(i as f32);
            if factor == factor.round() {
                let factor: i128 = factor as i128;
                if factor != val {
                    factors.push(factor)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println!("F32 {} {:?}", val, factors);
    if factors.is_empty() {
        return true
    } else {false}
}

fn is_prime_64(val:i128) -> bool {
    if val > 100 {
        return root_64(val)
    };
    return false
}
fn is_prime_32(val:i128) -> bool {
    if val > 100 {
        return root_32(val)
    };
    return false
}
fn main() {
    //let mut primes: Vec<i128> = vec![];
    let mut i:i128 = 16_777_210;
    loop {
        let prime_32: bool = is_prime_32(i);
        let prime_64: bool = is_prime_64(i);
        if prime_32 || prime_64 {
            println!("{} 32:{} 64:{}",i, prime_32, prime_64)
        }
        i += 1;
        if i > 16_777_260 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

We can see that initially factors lists are equal, but for `16777217` factors lists starts be different:

```
F32 16777210 [8388605, 3355442, 1677721]
F64 16777210 [8388605, 3355442, 1677721]

...

16777213 32:true 64:true

...

F32 16777217 [16777216, 8388608, 4194304, 2097152, 1048576, 524288, 262144, 131072, 65536, 32768, 16384, 8192, 4096]
F64 16777217 [172961, 65281, 24929]
```

We can note that

```
16777217 / (2^24) = 1.0000000596
```

but

```
16777216 / (2^24) = 1
```

So let's focus computing square from number `16777217`.

List of factors found by root_32 method indicates that `16777217` was approximated to `16777216` in comparison

```
factor == factor.round()
```

where `factor` is result of division

```
(val as f32)/(i as f32)
```

You can even write test for it

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        let result = 16777217 as f32 / 16777216 as f32;
        assert_eq!(result.round(), 1f32);
        assert_eq!(result, 1f32);
    }
}
```

If you are interested why `2^24` is crucial for this approximation you can read about `f32` structure

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html

especially about

```
pub const MANTISSA_DIGITS: u32 = 24u32
Number of significant digits in base 2.
```

### General advice

Both float division and modulo division are considered as heavy for CPU. You can read why here:

[Why is division more expensive than multiplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745819/why-is-division-more-expensive-than-multiplication)

And you should not use them in context of big numbers and computations. Instead I propose to implement Miller Rabin algorithm, that you can check here:

https://github.com/huonw/primal/blob/master/primal-check/src/is_prime.rs

If you really want to push it to limits you probably have to read some Curtis Cooper publications, learn about algorithms for quantum computers and wait when they will be ready :)

https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.6245

Comment: This fixing program but I will soon provide description why it make difference.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. It's still cursed though. Testing whether `val % i` is zero would be inherently unable to have this bug or any variant of this bug, but using `f64` delays the inevitable to some unknown higher number

Comment: For example for 18014398509481984 things go bad with `f64` (I did not check all numbers, so possibly for some lower numbers too)

Comment: @harold for f64 limit is 2^53 you can read about it in docs https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#associatedconstant.MANTISSA_DIGITS 

I do not really know what do you want yo achieve. If you need compute big prime numbers, lets start from reading scientific publications and other peoples code like this one: https://github.com/huonw/primal/blob/master/primal-check/src/is_prime.rs

Comment: Well, I don't really want to achieve anything, but I just think it's a bad practice to address this problem by just delaying it, using the same dodgy technique of dividing two floats and checking whether the result is the same after rounding it, when there is simple integer operator (simpler than OPs code if anything) that accomplishes the same goal without bugs. The MR primality test is cool too though (and of course, only uses integer arithmetic).